# KeyUp no funciona en algunos dispositivos móviles - ANGULAR

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, angular7, onkeyup

Los eventos `KeyUp` no funcionan en algunos dispositivos. En un `iPhone6` y `8` funciona bien, en un `Huawei P7` funciona también, pero en otro `Huawei` no está funcionando y en un `Samsung S7` tampoco.

Tengo un código que lo que hace es saltar al siguiente `input` cuando se ingresa un valor, cuando se completan los `4` los envía automáticamente haciendo un `POST`. Si se oprime la tecla de borrar se limpia todo el formulario.

```
keyup (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) {
        if (+e.key == 0 || +e.key) {
            this[`requestCode${+e.target.id}`] = e.key;
            if (+this.aux >= 0 && +this.aux < 4) {
                this.number[+e.target.id] = (this[`requestCode${+e.target.id}`]);
                this.aux++;
            }

            if (+this.aux == 4) {
                this.number[e.target.id] = +e.key;
            }

            let tempString = this.number.join();
            tempString = tempString.replace(/,/g, '');

            this.validate = tempString;
            this.jsf.updateValue(this, tempString);
            var validarSend = this.validate.indexOf("*");
            if(validarSend == -1) {
                // Valida si los 4 dígitos están completos antes de enviarlo
                let div: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeSubmit')[0] as HTMLElement;
                let element: HTMLElement = div.getElementsByTagName('button')[0] as HTMLElement;
                element.click();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    // Al presionarl Backspace reinicia los inputs    
    if(e.key == "Backspace"){            
        this.modelForm.reset();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Aquí tengo el `HTML` donde muestro 4 `inputs`.

```
<div [formGroup]=modelForm class="formsOtp">
    <br>
    <div class="transform-number">
        <input type="text" min="0" max="9" required="required" (keyup)="keyup($event)" id="0" fnFocus pattern="[0-9]*" class="inputOtp" inputmode="numeric"
            minlength="1" maxlength="1" formControlName=requestCode1 [ngModel]="requestCode0" autocomplete="off"> <div class="raya"></div> 
        <input type="text" min="0" max="9" required="required" (keyup)="keyup($event)" id="1" fnFocus pattern="[0-9]*" class="inputOtp" inputmode="numeric"
            minlength="1" maxlength="1" formControlName=requestCode2 [ngModel]="requestCode1" autocomplete="off"> <div class="raya"></div>  
        <input type="text" min="0" max="9" required="required" (keyup)="keyup($event)" id="2" fnFocus pattern="[0-9]*" class="inputOtp" inputmode="numeric"
            minlength="1" maxlength="1" formControlName=requestCode3 [ngModel]="requestCode2" autocomplete="off"> <div class="raya"></div> 
        <input type="text" min="0" max="9" required="required" (keyup)="keyup($event)" id="3" fnFocus pattern="[0-9]*" class="inputOtp" inputmode="numeric"
            minlength="1" maxlength="1" formControlName=requestCode4 [ngModel]="requestCode3" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button-validator">
    <p>¿No recibiste el código?<button mat-raised-button color=primary type="button" (click)="resendCode();">Has clic aquí</button></p> 
</div>
```

El problema no es que no pase al siguiente `input`, el problema está en que cuando se ingresa un carácter no hace el `POST`, no está haciendo el `Click` que se le está indicando.

Ya lo depuré y el valor que se retorna en el evento es `229` o es `undefined` en cualquier carácter que ingreso, no entra al primer `if`.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _"Ya lo depuré y el valor que se ingresa en `e` lo trae **229** y es **indefinido**"_? Dices que no entra al primer `if` pero entonces eso quiere decir que el evento `KeyUp` está funcionando.

Comment: Sí está entrando al evento, pero devuelve un KeyCode 229 de cualquier tecla.

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo tu comentario noto que los eventos `KeyUp` están funcionando, lo que no funciona bien es capturar el `keyCode` de la tecla que has presionado en algunos dispositivos Android. Pero una búsqueda rápida me deja ver [que no eres el único](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript) y que el problema no está en tu código. El `keyCode` debe devolver `229` si el `input` está siendo procesado [en caso de que el evento sea `KeyDown`](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html) (pero parece ser que en algunos dispositivos Android esto también ocurre en `KeyUp`).

Leyendo las respuestas del enlace de SO, se me ocurre algo similar a una de ellas y es hacer un procesamiento especial solo en Android para obtener el `keyCode` llamando al método [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charCodeAt) de `String` en el carácter acabado de escribir en vez de tomar el valor del evento. En el resto de los dispositivos tomar el valor del evento normalmente. Algo como lo siguiente (no lo he probado pero debe funcionar):

> Ten en cuenta que [`keyCode` está obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) y no es recomendado hacer uso de él. Lo recomendado es empezar a hacer uso de `code`.

```
private isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') >= 0;

private keyCode = function () {
    const input = this.currentTarget;
    return input.value.charAt(input.selectionStart - 1).charCodeAt();
};

keyup (e) {

    const code = this.isAndroid
        ? this.keyCode.call(e)
        : (e.code || e.keyCode);

    // Realizar tus chequeos
    if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
        ...
    }

}
```